# Отключение рабочего стола через раз

Tags: c++, c

Допустим, программа уже занесена в автозагрузку. Теперь нужно, чтобы программа запускала WinExec("taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe", 0); через раз. Ну там через реестр как-то это сделать. В смысле запустил винду, отключился рабочий стол. Перезагрузил, всё норм. А потом опять перезагрузил, опять рабочий стол отключается. Потом, опять норм. И так далее.

Comment: Ключевой вопрос: а зачем?

Comment: @S.H. что-то мне подсказывает, что это попытка подколоть кого-то :)

Comment: *Ну там через реестр как-то это сделать* приведите Ваши собственные попытки это сделать. Как известно, чтобы задать тут вопрос, следует самому попытаться что-то сделать. Например, погуглить "работа с реестром через cmd" или что-то подобное. Навскидку, как самый простой вариант, могу посоветовать при каждом запуске программы писать в файлик, например 0 или 1. Каждый раз, когда программа запускается, она читает значение из файла, если там 1, меняет её на 0 и убивает проводник, если 0, меняет на 1 и ничего больше не делает.